# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in with IF statement

Tags: php

Having issues with the following and I have not found an answer that would fit in yet...

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in ...
Code is :
public function query($query)
    {

```
    mysql_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'', $this->connection);

    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection);
    $this->counter++;

    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception('A MySQL error (#' . mysql_errno() . ' / ' . mysql_error() . ') occured in the following query: \'' . $this->parseQuery($query) . '\'');
    }

    if (in_array(strtoupper(array_shift(explode(' ', $this->parseQuery($query)))), array('SELECT', 'SHOW', 'EXPLAIN', 'DESCRIBE'))) 
    {
       $this->queries[] = $result;
    }
```

Problem is in this part : if (in_array(strtoupper(array_shift(explode(' ', $this->parseQuery($query)))), array('SELECT', 'SHOW', 'EXPLAIN', 'DESCRIBE')))

I tried to rewrite so it is not "nested"anymore...but no luck. I could use some help on this as my programming skills are not good enough

Answer (score 1):

It's in `array_shift` it only accepts variable reference:

```
$arr = explode(' ', $this->parseQuery($query));

if (in_array(strtoupper(array_shift($arr)), array('SELECT', 'SHOW', 'EXPLAIN', 'DESCRIBE'))) 
{
    $this->queries[] = $result;
}
```

This will work

Comment: Welcome Rob anytime, glad to help you

Comment: Is this one a similar problem ? As I run also into laguage setting issues. I solved it quick and dirty by just setting the language as fixed instead of being flexible....but I have the feeling it is related ... ?

Comment: $language = isset($_SESSION['language']) && in_array($_SESSION['language'], array_values($this->languages)) ? $_SESSION['language'] : 'nl';

Comment: I don't get it well, can you post it as new question?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<?php
    mysql_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'', $this->connection);

    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection);
    $this->counter++;

    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception('A MySQL error (#' . mysql_errno() . ' / ' . mysql_error() . ') occured in the following query: \'' . $this->parseQuery($query) . '\'');
    }
    $arr = array_shift(explode(' ', $this->parseQuery($query)));
    if (in_array(strtoupper($arr), array('SELECT', 'SHOW', 'EXPLAIN', 'DESCRIBE'))) 
    {
       $this->queries[] = $result;
    }
```

Comment: Yes I did, thanks for your help. I have one other that bugs me as well but I am not sure it is also an "array"issue.

Comment: call_user_func_array(array($class, $method), (array) $arguments);   it looks like this is not correct.....